# Alternative page when node is not translated

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I created a node and translated it in 3 of the 5 languages available on the site, when I'm on the node page and I switch to a language the page is not translated to the node remains in the language I came from, only the url changes from the clean url to node/1234 .

Is there a way to change this behavior and have it redirect to another page, like the home page or just show a 404 page?
I think I saw a checkbox once to alter something like this but i can't find it again.